# ng-animate a ul list

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I am trying to aniamte the act of hiding some li while showing some other li

```
<ul class="slides">
    <li ng-show="bullet1">
      <h1>The Fore-front of Design &amp; Technology</h1>
    </li>
    <li ng-show="bullet2">
      <h1>Multi-Purpose User Centric Design</h1>
    </li>
    <li ng-show="bullet3">
      <h1>Made with Love, Released for Free</h1>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="button-list">
    <button class="btn btn-circle" ng-click="changeBullet('bullet1')" ng-class="{'active': bullet1}">1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-circle" ng-click="changeBullet('bullet2')" ng-class="{'active': bullet2}">2</button>
    <button class="btn btn-circle" ng-click="changeBullet('bullet3')" ng-class="{'active': bullet3}">3</button>

  </div>
```

CSS as below:

```
.slides li  {
  -webkit-transition: all linear 1s;
  transition: all linear 1s;
}

.slides li.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

The transition effects of hiding and showing does not happen. Could someone point out what I am missing here ?

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/rzxgGgXiobnavy3XQqHu

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the display: none, and I'm almost sure that transition doesn't work on display.